# Wildcard parameter in WebAPI routing matching where it shouldn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a small ASP.NET WebAPI app and the only route I've set up is the following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{*furtherpath}"
);
```

I have the following controller:

```
public class FoldersController : ApiController {
    public string GetThis(DateTime queryStringDate) {
        return "abc";
    }

    public bool GetThat(string furtherpath) {
        return "xyz";
    }
}
```

I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I try to make this request, because it matches both of those method actions:

```
GET http://[server]/api/folders?queryStringDate=2015-02-11%2000:00:00
```

Now I would've thought this would unambiguously match `GetThis` because the requested URL doesn't contain the slash at the end which would separate `{controller}` and `{*furtherpath}`, and `furtherpath` is not marked as an optional parameter.  Why is this request ambiguous to WebAPI and how can I tell WebAPI that the lack of a slash after `folders` means that this request should match `GetThis`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcard in WebAPI Route template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725634/wildcard-in-webapi-route-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that both methods match the route.  `furtherpath` is seen as a parameter which is simply not used by the `GetThis` method.

You would really benefit from using attribute routing here.  Use this to register your routes:

```
config.MapAttributeRoutes();
```

And then decorate your methods with the routes:

```
public class FoldersController : ApiController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/folders/")]
    public string GetThis(DateTime queryStringDate) 
    {
        return "abc";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/folders/{furtherpath}")]
    public bool GetThat(string furtherpath) 
    {
        return "xyz";
    }
}
```

This will give you much more granular control over your routes.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725634/wildcard-in-webapi-route-template) provided by @luca-ghersi is very helpful as well.

Comment: But `furtherpath` isn't marked as an optional parameter, so if it's *not* there I don't see why `GetThat` matches (if I comment out the `GetThis` method, `GetThat` matches with `furtherpath` being set to `null`.

Comment: Yeah, I can't completely explain it without writing out the code and looking at the routes, but remember that Web Api does not look at the signature of the method as much as it looks at the route and matches the methods to the route.  Because both of your methods really only differ by the parameters (and the name), it's causing some confusion.  Attribute routing will solve this for you.  Debugging routes is one of the more difficult pieces of Web Api.

Comment: Ah, I thought it took method parameters into account.  It probably should.

Comment: It would be nice if it did.   Attribute routing is kinda the workaround for that.

Comment: @Jez - `furtherpath` *is* marked as an optional parameter implicitly because it is a wildcard. That basically tells it to match the rest of the URL regardless of what it is (and pass that value directly to the controller, even if it is empty).

Comment: NightOwl888 - Now THAT makes perfect sense.   Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @NightOwl888 OK but why does this: `api/folders?abc=def` match the route `api/{controller}/{*furtherpath}`?  That slash after `{controller}` doesn't seem optional.

Comment: @Jez - The `/` in the `url` is not a literal. It is a *segment delimiter*. Since the final segment is optional, so is the delimiter. See [URL Patterns on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#url_patterns). Note that using the URL `api/{controller}{*furtherpath}` is not valid (since it would not be possible to determine what part of the URL to put in each segment), so this behavior makes sense.

Comment: Yeah.  Why it doesn't pay attention to params I don't know; it clearly does during deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the "furtherpath" from route config, the route will be guided by your variables name.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/");

GET http://[server]/api/folders?queryStringDate=2015-02-11%2000:00:00
GET http://[server]/api/folders?furtherpath=2015-02-11%2000:00:00
```

Comment: That's no good because furtherpath would have to be a query string.  I want it to be able to be part of the main path.