# How to use regex routing in Azure Function c#

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have defined 4 attemps of using regex routing for my azure function, none of them work.

What have i done wrong?

```
public class ServerlessApi
{
    [FunctionName("Proxy")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "{test:regex(^\\/(subscriptions\\/[^\\/]+\\/)?(resourcegroups\\/[^\\/]+\\/)?providers\\/(Storage\\.IO))}")]HttpRequest req) => 
        new ProxyActionResult<FunctionHostStartup>();

    [FunctionName("Proxy1")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run1([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "{test:regex(^/(subscriptions/[^/]+/)?(resourcegroups/[^/]+/)?providers/(Storage\\.IO))}")]HttpRequest req) =>
      new ProxyActionResult<FunctionHostStartup>();

    [FunctionName("Proxy2")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run2(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "{path:regex(^/providers/Storage\\.IO)}")] HttpRequest req) 
        =>   new ProxyActionResult<FunctionHostStartup>();

    [FunctionName("Proxy3")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run3([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "{test:regex(^\\/providers\\/(Storage\\.IO))}")]HttpRequest req) =>
 new ProxyActionResult<FunctionHostStartup>();
}
```

I used to use nginx and had the following matching:
`$"~* ^/(subscriptions/[^/]+/)?(resourcegroups/[^/]+/)?providers/(Storage.IO)"`
Trying to do the same thing on my azure function.

Comment: i dont think its supported?

Comment: Instead of having four different functions, why can't you have one function that just determines which class will consume the message? I suppose it's also possible to have an http endpoint that will route messages to different queues based on regex expressions, but be careful when doing that as microservices-consuming-microservices can get complex very quickly.

Comment: The four examples were just me trying different things, none worked.

Comment: I am confused a bit how your URL could look like? Is it `<host>/subscriptions/resourcegroupse/providers/<some variable>` or rather `<host>/subscriptions/<some variable>` or it wouldn't have a variable part at all but rather some path parts could appear or disappear?

Comment: It will match /subscriptions/{id}/resourcegroups/{id}/providers/{id}, but /subscriptions/{id} and /resourcegroups/{id} parts can be optional, so just /providers/{id} is accessible. But just use proxy2 - its simpler and it do not work either.  I am concluding that regex routing is not supportet, but docs are saying so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I assume now I can help you a bit. The main point is that you should not use regexes here. What you should use here are [route parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#adding-route-attributes). According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#customize-the-http-endpoint) you should be able to use exactly the same syntax as Web API.

The problem here is that the URL could vary and we need to consider a few cases.

> It will match /subscriptions/{id}/resourcegroups/{id}/providers/{id}

Then define it like this

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "f1/subscriptions/{subid:int?}/resourcegroups/{resid:int?}/providers/{proid:int?}")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, int? subid, int? resid, int? proid)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Got s {subid}, r {resid}, p {proid}");
        }
```

Of course you should use types and constraints which make sense to you. The problem with this one is that you should really specify all the parameters `http://localhost:7071/api/f1/subscriptions/1/resourcegroups/0/providers/4`. You won't be able to write smt like `http://localhost:7071/api/f1/providers/4`. So I'd create a function for this and every other case, extracting the common logic in some another class/method:

```
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run2(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "f2/providers/{proid:int?}")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, int? proid)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Got p {proid}");
        }
```

Another possibility is to use the [wildcard parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19726381/467851), match the whole route to a variable and then parse it using a regex.